# Ubuntu is very slow

Tags: 12.04, lts

For some reason when I open up programs like firefox it take 3 seconds for it to open up.

I have 8 GB of RAM so it should be very fast. Also got quad core 3.5 ghz.

I already update it "apt-get update & apt-get upgrade"

Comment: Firefox is slow itself. Try to turn off add-ons or use Chrome. If other applications are slow, you should provide information about how is allocated space on your hard drive.

Answer (score 0):

I used on my Toshiba with 2 GB RAM:

```
sudo apt-get install preload
```

It worked very well, try to disable the Blur from you dash as well for more performance.